# Как определить, что запрос сделан с телефона или планшета?

Tags: delphi, indy

Как, в событие `idHttpServer.CommandGet`, определить, что запрос был сделан с телефона или планшета?

Comment: Включите в заголовки запроса в idHTTPClient "ImTablet=True"

Comment: клиент страничка в браузере

Comment: Страничка именно в браузере, или в webview?

Comment: в хроме, запрос такой document.location.replace("http://mysite.ru/Loading/Games?username=